# Restangular - How to create a API on top of it

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have started using [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) for my AngularJS project and want to create a service using Restangular to make REST calls. The service would have a function like this:

```
getAll
$scope.account = save($scope.account)
$scope.account = update(account)
```

Now since a Restangular call returns a promise inside the service which would have to be called like then() to get the results, how do I return the fetched or updated result from my service wrapper?

I want to create a wrapper API so that I can have any other business logic after I fetch the record and then return back the result from my service API. I can use the Restangular service directly in my controller but I need a proper service layer to be called from controller which would return me the result of the REST call and not just a promise.

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make use of promise chaining.

So in your service you would have (notice we are returning the promise):

```
this.save = function(newAccount) {
  ..... // Do business logic on account before submit
  return restangular.all('accounts').post(newAccount).then(function(result){
    ...... // Do business logic after successful save
    return newAccount;
  }, function(error){
    ...... // Do business logic on error
  });
};
```

And then inside your controller:

```
$scope.saveAccount = function(newAccount) {
  service.save(newAccount).then(function(savedAccount){
    $scope.account = savedAccount;
  }, function(errror) {
   ..... // Error handling
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. My save, update and getList are working. My remove have a double promise chain. Can you please let me know how to chain it ?      this.remove = function(account) {
        return Restangular.one("accounts", account.id).get().then(function(account) {
                account.remove().then(function(result){
                    return result;
                }), function(error){
                     // Do business logic on error
                };

        });
    }

Comment: Actually I chained the promise again in return and it worked. Thank you so much.